# ARC stuck in infinite retain or release loop

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have an older app that I converted to use ARC. The original version did not have memory leaks, and I fixed all of the errors after the conversion using the memory diagnostics in the debugger. Occasionally, the app will crash and the stack trace looks like ARC is stuck in either an infinite retain or release cycle, like this:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x329046a6 CFRelease + 46
1   CoreFoundation                  0x329046da CFRelease + 98
2   CoreFoundation                  0x329046da CFRelease + 98
3   CoreFoundation                  0x329046da CFRelease + 98
4   CoreFoundation                  0x329046da CFRelease + 98
```

Unfortunately, the stack traces cut off at 512 entries, so I can't see where this chain started. Apple said this could happen if the alloc and init methods are separated and the init method returns a different object than alloc. I checked all of our allocations and they follow the recommended format:

```
Class *var = [[Class alloc] initMethod:arg];
```

Has anyone seen an infinite loop of this sort? I have not been able to catch it while using the Xcode debugger, and it is very inconsistent. Since ARC is injecting the retains and releases, I don't have any idea where the crash originates.

Comment: Can you post your initMethod?

Comment: That was just a generic sample. Obviously, I can't post every single init method because there are hundreds of them. Our code doesn't ever return a different `self` in the init from the alloc, but some SDK classes do. Here is an actual example from our code: `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];`

Comment: Oh, I thought you had narrowed down the class involved. Do you have consistent repro steps (like staying on screen X for Y minutes)? Have you run the static analyzer or Instruments?

Comment: Have you tried logging in dealloc?  Probably not going through there, but worth a shot.

Comment: No, I don't have an idea of which class is causing the problem. Sometimes it is a loop of releases, and sometimes it is a loop of retains. There is no consistent set of steps to reproduce the problem. The app depends heavily on downloading data from a web service. The time I was able to reproduce the error, I started the app on wifi, backgrounded it, turned off wifi, waited 30 minutes, then brought it back to the foreground. I have run Instruments, as well as the memory management diagnostics. I can't use the simulator because my current testing relies on having a cellular connection.

Comment: Use the debugger to break on CFRelease().